# Formula for counting how many cells contain a specific text, while ignoring other entries in the same cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet that measures how many NOs (entered as N) and PARTIALs (entered as P) are marked against an employee via a Scoring Sheet that is used to measure performance. For example, if the Scoring Sheet has 10 Steps, and they received a full NO in Step 1 and PARTIAL in Step 10, I would document "N 1, P 10".

At the end of each month, I would like to begin counting how many times each Step was missed for the entire month, regardless of it was marked as a full NO (N) or PARTIAL (P). So, in other words if someone received 5 separate Scoring Sheets in the month, and out of those 5 Scoring Sheets, they received 3 NOs for Step 1 and 2 PARTIALs for Step 1, I want it recognize both as one and the same, and return a number of 5 total variances for that Step.

Here is an example of a month where six Scoring Sheets were completed, with all the NOs, PARTIALs, and NAs (Non-applicables) were captured:

[image: Example1]

Ignoring all the other text (such as Overturned, non-urgent, and CoW Nominee), I would like to capture how many times each Step was marked as either a N or P. As you can see, some cells contain both Ns and Ps for different Steps. Ideally, I would have a table such as in the image below that shows how many times each Step was marked as either N or P:

[image: Example2]

What formula or formulas can I use that will look through each cell in the first image above and count how many times each Step was marked as either N or P?

Thank you!

Comment: You should add to your question 1) the formula you currently use to resolve the issue 2) example of the expected output 3) example of actual output. You will get advice on why the formula might be failing, but it's very unlikely anyone's going to write one for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the
[COUNTIF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34).

Assuming an `N` followed by a blank is one result, and the same for `P`,
the formula for your example is:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:F1,"*N *")+COUNTIF(A1:F1,"*P *")
```

Once it works for row 1, you may drag drown to extend the formula
down over the rows below.

Note: The regular expression inside the above quotes can be further
tweaked if other value names may terminate with `N` or `P`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This formula seems to be working in some cases, but it also counting every entry of "10" (such as N 10 or P 10) in the total count for "1" as well (such as N 1 or P 1). How do I get it to only count the specific number 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on?

Comment: Take the count for "1" you currently get and substract the count of "10" to get the correct count for "1"